# mysql match/against

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

I'm using this search

-> match (c1, c2) against (">dg*" in boolean mode);

and I get this list

1 dgas

2 dgica

3 dgicb

4 dgii

5 dgit

6 dgly

7 dgc

8 dgse

which seems reasonable.

The problem is that I DON'T get "dgl", which I know is there in column c1.

So I DO get "dgly" but NOT "dgl".

I find this confusing and would appreciate any thoughts.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL fulltext indexing will, by default, ignore words that are shorter than four characters.

This can be changed at the server level by setting [`ft_min_word_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) to a smaller number and then rebuilding the fulltext indexes.

[Here's more information in the manual about fine-tuning fulltext searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).