# Mysql -> MATCH AGAINST FULL TEXT SEARCH

Tags: mysql, match, match-against

I have a table with millions of records, for example:

```
id  Name   Age
1   john    23
2   peter   27
3   moses   23
```

....
....

Like this using MySQL MATCH AGAINST query. I want to pick the third row which has
name *moses* & age *23*.

I can use an ordinary query like:
`select from table where name='moses' && age ='23'`

But this takes a lot of time.
So, my friend told me to use a Match Against Query.
Can anyone tell me whether we can do this in a Match Against Query and its advantages?

How can we write the above query using a `MATCH() ... AGAINST` syntax?

Comment: It is already asked in stackoverflow.
Refer these links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304138/mysql-match-against
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366840/mysql-match-against

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t
WHERE MATCH(t.Name) AGAINST('moses')
      AND t.Age=23
```

Comment: why you r not writing age using match against

Comment: MYSQL :: Natural Language Full-Text Searches (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)